# Python method where first argument is either class or self

Tags: python

I want to write some Python code that when called from the context of a type behaves like an `@classmethod`, however when called on an instance of an object the first argument is behaves as normal, with `self` referencing the current instance. I.e. I want to write:

```
class Foo(object):
    @something # <- does this exist? How can I even write it?
    def bar(self_or_class):
        print(repr(self_or_class))

Foo.bar() # Should print: <class '__main__.Foo'>
inst = Foo()
inst.bar() # Should print:  <__main__.Foo at 0x....>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once wrote a code snippet in [daniweb](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/406393/mixedmethod-mixes-class-and-instance-method-into-one) about this

```
from __future__ import print_function
from functools import partial

class mixedmethod(object):
    """This decorator mutates a function defined in a class into a 'mixed' class and instance method.

    Usage:

        class Spam:

            @mixedmethod
            def egg(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
                if self is None:
                    pass # executed if egg was called as a class method (eg. Spam.egg())
                else:
                    pass # executed if egg was called as an instance method (eg. instance.egg())
    The decorated methods need 2 implicit arguments: self and cls, the former being None when
    there is no instance in the call. This follows the same rule as __get__ methods in python's
    descriptor protocol.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return partial(self.func, instance, cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    class Spam(object):

        @mixedmethod
        def ham(self, cls, *args):
            if self is None:
                print("Spam.ham() was called as a class method with {0}.".format((self, cls)+ args))
            else:
                print("Spam.ham() was called as an instance method with {0}.".format((self, cls) + args))

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Spam instance>'
    egg = Spam()
    egg.ham(5)
    Spam.ham(5)
```

Comment: I wish I'd found that an hour ago

Comment: @Flexo The only drawback of this idea is that is not really useful. One can as well write a class method and an instance method with a different name. Normally, client code knows whether the argument is a type or an instance.

Comment: The use I have is in cross language interoperability. I.e. to make a 1:1 mapping of behaviour between Python proxies to other languages you have to do this.

Comment: @Flexo that's a nice use case!

Answer (score 1):

After some research I managed to do this. The first thing I found is that you can actually [implement `@classmethod` in pure Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods), as referenced in the documentation.

With that knowledge it's fairly simple to adapt the code to test if `obj` exists:

```
class something(object):
    ''' 
    This works like @classmethod, except the first argument is either class or self if it's available
    '''
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(obj)
        def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.f(klass if obj is None else obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return newfunc
```

All we have to do over and above the example in the documentation is check if `obj` is `None` and favour `obj` over `klass` if it is not.